# Runtime error with footer's resizing using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working with PHP, and this footer is one of the components of every page. First off, I know that a footer of this size needs to be made smaller before I publish it; it's currently formatted like this before I create drop-down (or in this case, pop-up) menus.

I currently have jQuery set to auto-resize the footer's height on window resize (with debounce), since the internal elements move in a grid pattern. However, I've run into a couple issues:

1. On the first page load, before any resizes, it doesn't extend the footer sufficiently far enough so all internal elements are on the same colored background. I know I could just add a  constant, but I want it to scale with the end user's default text size.
2. <strike>After multiple resizes, the footer's total height is several times more than intended.</strike>

I can't spot the error; what am I doing wrong? I've pasted the relevant code into jsFiddle, as it's rather long.

[Code (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wrzv/6/)

EDIT: Problem 2 fixed. Default behavior is now Problem 1.

EDIT 2: Here's a preview. You should still checkout the fiddle, though.

```
var maxWidth, maxHeight, numBoxes;

function arrangeFooter() {
    // Get the width of the footer to determine # of rows
    var footerWidth = $("#footer").width();

    // Get list of .box divs' widths and lengths
    var widths = $(".box").map(function() {
        return $(this).innerWidth();
    }).get();

    var heights = $(".box").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    numBoxes = widths.length;

    // Find maxWidth, maxHeight of .box divs
    // From these, finds # of cols that can fit with the maxWidth,
    // and number of rows
    maxWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, widths);
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);
    var cols = Math.floor(footerWidth / maxWidth);
    var rows = Math.ceil(numBoxes / cols);

    // Calculates footer's new height, defined as 
    // maxHeight * num rows + height of .firstrow div
    var newHeight = maxHeight * rows + parseFloat($(".firstrow").css("font-size"));

    // Prints out resulting CSS rules directly to page
    var styling = "\n  .box {\n    height: " + maxHeight + "px;\n    width: " + 
                    maxWidth + "px;\n  }\n"
    styling += "\n  #footer {\n    height:" + newHeight + "px;\n  }\n";
    $("#style").text(styling);
}

function resizeFooter() {
    var footerWidth = $("#footer").width();

    var cols = Math.floor(footerWidth / maxWidth);
    var rows = Math.ceil(numBoxes / cols);

    // Calculates footer's new height, defined as 
    // maxHeight * num rows + height of .firstrow div
    var newHeight = maxHeight * rows + parseFloat($(".firstrow").css("font-size"));

    // Prints out resulting CSS rules directly to page
    $('#footer').css('height',newHeight);
}

// Debounce method; used to ensure that only one event is fired
// after ms if multiple identical events are triggered
var delay = (function() {
    var timers = {};
    return function(callback, ms, uniqueId) {
        if (!uniqueId) {
            uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
        }
        if (timers[uniqueId]) {
            clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
        }
        timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

function init() {
    // calls arrangeFooter after 200ms to ensure page loads first
    setTimeout(arrangeFooter, 200);
    // Problem? Executes 500ms after window resize is "complete"
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        delay(function() {
            resizeFooter();
        }, 500, "resize");
    });
}

window.onload = init();​
```

Comment: Superficially, the code looks fine to me. Maybe there's a bug somewhere else? Have you tried dumping newHeight, maxHeight and rows out to console on each loop?

Comment: @blueberryfields Yes, I have. Both `maxHeight` and `rows` are only defined once (when the page initially loads); only `newHeight` changes on every resizing.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If all the elements going into the calculation for newHeight remain constant, newHeight should remain constant, too.

Comment: @blueberryfields D'oh! That was part of the problem, but now it defaults to problem #1.

Comment: Am I missing part of the code there? I don't see the part that takes your newHeight value and makes the height of the footer. I put $('#footer').css('height',newHeight); in at the end of arrangeFooter() and it works for me. And I know I can do it with .height(), just didn't for some reason -_-

Comment: @GuruMeditation I had it printed directly onto the page, like so, rather that print it into a tag's `style` attribute: `var styling = "\n  .box {\n    height: " + maxHeight + "px;\n    width: " + maxWidth + "px;\n  }\n"
    styling += "\n  #footer {\n    height:" + newHeight + "px;\n  }\n";
    $("#style").text(styling);`

Comment: @GuruMeditation I just tried it your way (on my own page and jsfiddle), but it still didn't work.

Comment: I screwed up while looking at the code the first time and accidentally axed the <style id='style'></style> part. Hadn't seen that before :) Still looking.

Comment: I'm not sure to what degree it isn't working for you :( From my end in JSFiddler it wasn't off by much, but I added parseFloat($(".firstrow").css("padding-bottom")) to newHeight as well as font-size and that made it work, but it was only off by a few pixels for me.

Comment: @GuruMeditation Well, for some reason, when I added `parseFloat($(".firstrow").css("padding-bottom"))`, it went berserk and did #2 twice over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7871/discussion-between-gurumeditation-and-edwin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with the code a bit I think the problem is related to adding the font size of the first row to the size of the content in the box div.

This will add about 16 pixels to the height, but won't add the margin (10 pixels), padding (another 10 pixels) or border (1 pixel). Furthermore if the screen is so thin that for some reason that row extends to two lines then it'll only add the font-size once and not twice.

Therefore I propose the alternative:

```
var newHeight = maxHeight * rows + $(".firstrow").outerHeight(true);
```

.outerHeight(true) will give you the height of the element including margins.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, but `.outerHeight(true)` just magnifies the error. I'm using the `border-box` property, so both `.height()` and `.width()` return the padding in the calculation. Perhaps I should move .firstrow's `margin-bottom` to .box's `margin-top`? I'll check it out.

Comment: Dang, sorry I wasn't able to help :/ Out of curiosity what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X + Chrome. I occasionally do testing with Safari and FF as well.

Comment: Stupid me. Just realized I used `.outerWidth(true)` instead of `.outerHeight(true)`. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Thank you for confirming that was the case, I thought I was going crazy >_<